# HttpClient GetAsync(url) throws "The request was aborted. Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Tags: c#, ssl, httpclient

I have tried the following C#-code, but get exception when GetAsync() is called. Using Firefox with same request I am able to get a response. Any ideas how I can make the code work in C#? The server is old and out of my control btw.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
var url = $"https://ipadress/query";
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);

if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Are you able to get a response using IE? IE uses the OS's SSL support, as does .NET, but Firefox brings its own along.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the `=> true;` part to see if that gets hit at all?

Comment: No, IE does not work. I've tried breakpoint in the callback-function. But it never gets hit.

Comment: Might be worth checking your internet options and seeing if SSL 3 is unticked in there. (Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Advanced Tab. Scroll down to Security and see which "Use Xxx M.m" options are ticked)